# React JS - how to get google-map-react to work?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-react

I want to put two maps on my page but I'm not able to. This is what I got:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can anyone help me?

This is the result [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function Map is using the useState hook, this is not permitted and yields the error you are getting in the console.

You only need to use regular variable declarations:

Intead of:

```
const [status,setStatus] = useState(null)
```

Just declare it as

```
let status = null
```

And instead of using setStatus, just reassign the value using plain JS:

```
status = "new value"
```

EDIT: I see you got more errors in the console but this will at least fix one

Refer to https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html to know more about said rules